# XAML IMultiValueConverter Width Auto or *

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am developing an application in WPF MVVM . I wish for a Width property , with a converter, or * Auto return . My converter returns good values ​​but to no avail . Here, my Converter

```
 class FicheWidthVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    int SizeDatagrid = 0;
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var VisibilityFiche = (Visibility)values[1];
        var NewSizeDataGrid = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);

        //Récupère la taille AUTO du datagrid
        if (SizeDatagrid == 0)
            SizeDatagrid = NewSizeDataGrid;

        //Si la taille di datagrid a changé
        if (NewSizeDataGrid < SizeDatagrid)
        {
            if (VisibilityFiche == Visibility.Visible)
                return "*";
        }
        return "Auto";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

and in ma View

```
<ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource FicheWidthVisibilityConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding ElementName="Datagrid" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="Fiche" Path="Visibility"/>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ColumnDefinition.Width>
        </ColumnDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return value of type `GridLength` instead of plain string. So you should replace `return "*";`  with `return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);` and `return "Auto"` with `return GridLength.Auto;`. `GridLength` class belongs to `System.Windows` namespace